# Django image thumbnails solution using rackspace CloudFiles

Tags: django, thumbnails, rackspace-cloud, django-models

I have a high load django project with a lot of images in it (in django.db.models.ImageField).
I'm looking for a solution with the following criteria:

1. Images are stored in Rackspace CloudFiles (using django-cumulus)
2. Images' thumbnails are stored in cloud too
3. Thumbnails are generated at the same moment as source image changes (I **don't** want thumbnails to be generated on template render as most of django's thumbnails libraries do)

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: What libraries have you tried so far?

Comment: you might want to check this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912041/changing-django-storages-backend-from-from-s3-to-cloudfiles-and-dealing-with-old

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1) you should be able to use `django-cumulus`, I'm not aware of another working package for Rackspace CloudFiles.

For (2) set the [`STATICFILES_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-storage) setting to point to the class which handles static files on the cloud. In my case I store my user-uploaded static files on Amazon S3, and I extend the `S3BotoStorage` class imported this way:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage
```

from `django-storages`. Find what the equivalent class is for the `django-cumulus` module and use/extend accordingly; storage classes are in [here](https://github.com/richleland/django-cumulus/blob/master/cumulus/storage.py). The key is to set `STATICFILES_STORAGE` to point to it.

For (3) use your thumbnail generation library to "fetch" the image at the various thumbnail sizes you need when the source image changes. This will create them immediately (if they do not exist yet). (This applies for the libraries I have used, which are [`sorl-thumbnail`](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [`easy_thumbnails`](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/).

Side note: "asynchronous generation" of thumbnails (so that the initial request does not have to wait for all thumbnails to be generated immediately) is a popular requirement, and it is fairly documented for the `easy_thumbnails` library [here](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#asynchronous-pregeneration). Should be straightforward to set up if you have `celery` already enabled in your architecture.

Comment: the Rackspace module for `django-storages` is outdated/deprecated. We recommend using a different solution. If you **must** use `django-storages`, it's adviced you extend it using libcloud.

Comment: @rdodev Thanks, since it works well for Amazon S3 I've assumed it works well for CloudFiles; didn't use it myself. What is the alternative?

Comment: Check the comment section of this Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912041/changing-django-storages-backend-from-from-s3-to-cloudfiles-and-dealing-with-old

Comment: No prob. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for (3) standart thumnail generation on the fly will be still enabled. so when thumbnail is not completely generated and server gets several http hits on target page, can it cause easy_thumbnails to generate same thumbnail many times simultaneously?

Comment: @Antonio Good question. In my experience I prevented that from happening by adding thumbnail generation to the "upload" process. I.e. I do not return a response to the user until the file has been uploaded and thumbnails generated. The front-end gives a nice "waiting" message, so that the site does not seem unresponsive while it is doing the work for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Sounds like a plan) I'll try this!

Comment: `django-stdimage` should work with `s3boto` as well, if not let me know.